# Script to delete all folders except

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I found a script that will delete all folders except a certain one

```
for /d %i in ("C:\test\*") do if /i not "%~nxi"=="test2" rd /q "%i"
```

How do you change this to add more folders that I don't want deleting?

Comment: This does not work for me for  1 folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set "list=test1 test2 test3"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "delete=0"
pushd "C:\test\"
for /d %%i in (*) do (
   set "delete=1"
   for %%# in (%list%) do (
    if /i "%%i" equ "%%#" (
        set "delete=0"
        echo  %%i will be not deleted
    )
  )
  if !delete!==1 (
    rd /s /q "%%i"
  )

)
popd
```

Comment: hi sorry it doesnt delete the other folders    it says "the directory is not empty under each folder check

Comment: sorry to be a pain your change now delete the test folder

Comment: @Phairplay - you are absolutely right.I'm an idiot.Now fixed and tested.Best regards.

Comment: it's still deleting the test folder :(

Comment: @Phairplay - it deletes the root dir?

Comment: Yes sorry it deletes the root